# git cherry-pick without fetching remote branch

Tags: git, github, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I am having a bit of a problem here, I want to cherry-pick a commit from a git repo that isn't locally present in my system.

For example : https://github.com/DespairFactor/N6/commit/ecea4ab6d3d8bb4122522398200f1cd2a06af6d5

A usual cherry-picking procedure includes doing

1) `git remote add <RepoName> <repoURL>`

2) `git fetch <RepoName>` and it downloads a copy but isn't merged to your own local repo.

3) `git cherry-pick <commit SHA>` and cherry-pick is done.

I have a very slow download speed (1 mbps), and I don't have enough time to download whole repo for 1 commit. Sorry if this question was already asked and answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might consider to download the patch, then apply it locally.

To get the patch for a specific commit on GitHub, simply append the `.patch` suffix to the commit URL:

https://github.com/DespairFactor/N6/commit/ecea4ab6d3d8bb4122522398200f1cd2a06af6d5.patch

And some variant forms:

- https://github.com/git/git/commit/HEAD.patch
- https://github.com/git/git/commit/master~3.patch

See: https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets#diff-patch

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: Hi, Sameer, it's about the syntax, more specifically the `.patch` suffix, the repo url was from the question and it actually doesn't matter.

Comment: `curl https://github.com/DespairFactor/N6/commit/ecea4ab6d3d8bb4122522398200f1cd2a06af6d5.patch | git am`